# Error message Time Manager plugin with QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, timemanager

I am using QGIS version 2.14.0 (Essen) and have downloaded the latest version of the Time Manager plugin in order to do some spatial-temporal analysis.

I have imported a csv file into QGIS and made a join wih a shapefile in order to import all the time data on the shapefile. However, when I use this shapefile in Time Manager, it recognises the data as the start date appears in the player time frame, but the video and animation do not load. In the logs I see the folowing error message:

```
Exception in function <function refreshTimeRestrictions at 0x0ECA18F0>:'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using time data in the followng format, which should be compatible with Time Manager:

YYYY-MM-DD

Sample data:

```
start_date          end_date            start_date_auto     end_date_auto 
2016-04-01 00:00    2017-11-01 00:00    2016-04-01 00:00    2017-11-01 00:00 
2016-01-01 00:00    2018-01-01 00:00    2016-01-01 00:00    2018-01-01 00:00 
2015-03-09 00:00    2016-12-31 00:00    2015-03-09 00:00    2016-12-31 00:00
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: you might want to post some of the data from the csv.

Comment: http://www.charbase.com/00e9-unicode-latin-small-letter-e-with-acute
This is the character that is causing you problems. You shouldn't have this in the date field

Comment: I tried but it still doesnt work. now the error message is as follows (i truncated it as it is toolong):

Exception: Could not match value 03-02-16 00:00 with any of the supported formats. Tried ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%HZ', '%Y-%m-%d',

Comment: I think you need to convert `03-02-16 00:00` to `03-02-2016 00:00` (year must have 4 digits).

Comment: I changed the data again but yet again i get the first error message. Is it just the selected column this character cant be in or is it the file name and any other column of the csv?

Exception in function :'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: To be in the safe side, I would avoid using any type of symbols in the entire file (including file name, columns, data etc).

Comment: I've changed all these chracters and replaced them but I still get th same error message in the logs. Plus a new red message which i didnt get before which says:"Copy of Pentagone._programmes_start_date" not recognised as an available field"

"Copy of Pentagone._programmes_start_date" is the name of the colum i am using

Comment: Alos does the data in the csv i'm trying to import have to be in STRING format or DATE format?

Comment: Please share test data otherwise we are limited to guessing ...

Comment: Here is my data:

start_date end_date start_date_auto end_date_auto
2016-04-01 00:00 2017-11-01 00:00 2016-04-01 00:00 2017-11-01 00:00
2016-01-01 00:00 2018-01-01 00:00 2016-01-01 00:00 2018-01-01 00:00
2015-03-09 00:00 2016-12-31 00:00 2015-03-09 00:00 2016-12-31 00:00